# ETL-Some of records required to run the KTR's again to upload data to destination

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle, spoon

I am using Kettle-spoon for ETL process. when ever i run the KTR to upload the data many of the records are uploaded but some of them are gone missed and not properly upload. but if i run the KTR for that specific(Missing Record) Record it successfully upload that records. if any one knows what is the reason behind that issuee.

Comment: can you explain which steps you are using?

Comment: I am using HTTP post.

Comment: i am asking about sequence,can you share the sequence of steps you are using?

Comment: sorry i can't i don't have any issuee in any step. i have debugged it many time. some time all the data is uploaded at one go.